# Formatting issues in asp.net integrated ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I'm using asp.net integrated ckeditor and having issues with content formatting like Bold, Italic & Underline. We had to press multiple times.

Any work around for this ? Using 3.6.6.2 version

Answer (score 4):

The situation with using CKEditor in the ASP.NET environment looks as follows:

- The official CKEditor for ASP.NET control has not been updated to CKEditor v4 yet.
- It is possible to manually update the editor version used with the .NET control to the latest v4 version, however, this will not give you all capabilities of CKEditor 4 because e.g. you will only have access to configuration options existing in the v3. I will list the steps required to perform such update by yourself below.
- The CKEditor 3 line only gets security updates. No new features or code backports are done for this version and all development now happens in the v4 line.

You are of course free to replace the CKEditor library (the editor itself) in the existing ASP.NET integration with the latest version of CKEditor 4.x. Depending on what you need, it may fit your needs. That will fix e.g. the various IE problems. From what I understand inline editing won't work, though.

Here are the steps needed to manually update CKEditor version inside the v3.6.6.2 ASP.NET control (the latest ASP.NET version):

- [Download CKEditor 3.6.6.2 for ASP.NET](http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor.NET/CKEditor.NET%203.6.6.2/ckeditor_aspnet_3.6.6.2.zip) and unpack it.
- Go to `your-ckeditor-aspnet-3.6.6.2-folder\_Samples` and delete the `\ckeditor\` directory.
- [Download the FULL package for CKEditor 4.4.7](http://ckeditor.com/download) and extract it to the `\ckeditor\` directory.
- Next copy the `\ckeditor\` directory to `your-ckeditor-aspnet-3.6.6.2-folder\_Samples`.

Please note, in particular, that in CKEditor 4.1 we have introduced [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf) (ACF). If you plan to use the content filter, you would have to use `config.js` to change ACF settings as it can’t be done from the control level.

Last but not least, CKEditor is a pure JavaScript application, so in most cases you can probably just use the standard installation package and use the JavaScript integration instead of the ASP.NET control.