# is "CKEditor for ASP.NET" deprecated?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I'm looking at the download page for ckeditor and I see that the ASP.NET control was last released in 2014.  The version string is 3.6.6.2.  Does this mean that the control is deprecated?  It seems to work properly w/ 4.4.x, but I'm chasing down some weird ckeditor control issues and I wanted to make sure this isn't somehow the cause.

Some of the weird issues I've been chasing

- Sometimes when I'm doing a save via form submit, I'll get an exception thrown by the guts of ckeditor: **Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'extend' on 'Selection': 1 is larger than the given node's length.**

  - Selecting text in the control prior to save makes it go away
  - Only happens in Chrome from what I can tell
  - If I remove the divarea plugin, that makes it go away
- I feel like sometimes I'm getting weird errors with it complaining that jquery is missing when I use the asp.net control -- they don't seem to happen under the markup / script based method.  I haven't pinned this down yet.

The overall build is the 3.6.6.2 of the asp.net control.  The ckeditor build is 4.4.7.  There are custom config.js files used in some places and in some places the control is configured by markup in the asp.net control.

Comment: You might want to strengthen your question by stating what issues you are facing.

Comment: Please [check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029072/formatting-issues-in-asp-net-integrated-ckeditor/30075453#30075453), I tried to explain the current status of the ASP.NET control.

Comment: So it seems like it is ok to keep using it until a v4 release is accomplished.  I think what you outlined is what was basically done by my coworkers.  I think I can rule out the ASP.NET control as a factor, perhaps.

Comment: CKEditor is an Open Source project, so if you or your organization feel like you could benefit from an updated CKEditor for ASP.NET control and be willing to help, either through collaboration or sponsorship, it would be most welcome if you [got in touch with us](http://cksource.com/contact) at CKSource.